# Rerendering a model in admin that accesses both an m2m field and a foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model called `Statement` and it has a field called "keyword_pairs" that creates a  with another model called `KeywordInContext`.

`KeywordInContext` has two fields: "keyword" and "context". "keyword" develops a foreignkey with an instance of a model called  `Keyword`. "context" develops a m2m relationship with the model `Keyword`. This is creating a pairing system so that each Keyword has a set of keywords it can pair with.

However, the way that the admin change page for `Statement`s renders the `KeywordInContext` model is just with the default drop down box for m2m relationships. This drop down box allows you to select the "keyword" field of the `KeywordInContext` model, but doesn't allow any modification or adding of "contexts." Someone would simply be able to update/add a statement and implicitly say "this `Statement` has a bunch of `KeywordInContext` objects with their "keyword" field set to what I select from this drop down menu." But they to actually add the context that they want to specify for the keyword, they would have to go the change page for KeywordInContext.

This inhibits a paired submission of a 'keyword' and 'context' to add on to the  'keyword_pairs' on the admin side. What can I do to change this?
Here is the code for models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Statement(models.Model):
    statement_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    issue_date = models.DateField("Issue-Date")
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    released_by = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField('KeywordInContext')

 @python_2_unicode_compatible
 class KeywordInContext(models.Model):
     keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword)
     contexts = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, related_name='keyword_context')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword.word + ' (' + ', '.join(c.word for c in self.contexts.all()) + ')' #We temporarily changed the __str__ method to show all of the contexts for a keyword.
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding the issue, it sounds like inlines are what you are after. The docs have a pretty clear example:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects